# Find when $x$ and $\cos{nx}$ make a right angle

Tags: trigonometry

For what value of $n$ does $x$ and $\cos{nx}$ make a right angle at their intersection?The problem is I don't know how to find $ \cos nx=x$.

Not sure if this helps, but for the case of $x=\cos x$, $x=\cos\cos\cos...\cos(k)$, where cos is iterated infinitely many times, and for any value $k$.

Comment: If $x$ is a real number, what does it mean for $x$ and $\cos nx$ to make a right angle?

Comment: It would mean nsin(na) has a slope of 1, where a=cos(na), correct?

Comment: I wasn't seeing them as functions.  You are correct.  Are you meaning the $n^{\text{th}}$ iterate of $\cos x$, not $\cos(nx)$?

Comment: No, not the nth iterate, actually $\cos(nx)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is not algebraic way to find this.  Even solving $x = \cos x$ is done numerically (giving $x\approx 0.73908513321516064166$)  The functions are well behaved, so numerics converge easily.

Comment: There's no way known, or has it been proven that there's no way? If we define $d$ as the root of $\cos x - x$, is it possible to find a solution in terms of $d$?

Comment: I don't know of a proof.  Polynomials and trig functions do not play nice together, so solutions to mixed equations don't happen.  Are you assuming $n$ is an integer?  For most $x$ it won't be.  If you count on it being an integer, you can use the multiple angle relations to check possibilities until you find the right one.

Comment: No, I know that $n$ is about 51/24 and less than 2, so definitely not an integer. Let's say that the right angle for occurs when $x=a$. Then we could say that $1=n\sin(na)$, correct? Solving this system of equations, if I did it correctly, gives $n=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-1}{a^2}}$. Substituting back into $a=\cos(na)$ gives $a=\cos{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$. Although I doubt it, could this be of any use?

Comment: You have $\frac d{dx} \cos (nx)=-n \sin (nx) = -1$, so you are correct that $1= n sin (na)$  Over the small range $\frac {51}{24}$ to $2$ we could calculate a number of points as a function of $n$ to reasonably high precision, then fit a polynomial through them, and use that to determine it for other $n$.  It will be quite accurate that way.